# Apache Spark: executors stuck on Python warnings

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, warnings

I was running some tests with Pyspark and stumbled upon a strange thing - Spark executors seem to halt execution without failing after receiving relatively harmless warnings from Python code. In my case warnings came from Pandas notifying me that some of the methods were deprecated.

So the question why this is happening and what Spark settings can I play with to avoid it?

- spark 2.3.0 upon EMR
- python 2.7.13
- pandas: 0.23.0

The warning message:

```
warning: 'FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead'
```

Also it seems that this doesn't happen immediately after the first warning received by executors, but rather after some critical mass was reached (im my case probably several dozens of warnings per exec).

Comment: More information is required.  What version of Spark? What version of Python?  What version of Pandas?  Can you share the exact message?

Comment: What exactly happens within the executor log? Can you show it?